# Cohomological dimension of the kernel of a homomorphism induced by a singular fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

I have a very concrete question. Let $N={\Bbb C}-\{\pm 1\}$, and ${\Bbb Z}_2$ is acting on $N$ by rotation around $0$. Consider $M=\{(x,y)\in N^2\ |\ {\Bbb Z}_2x\neq {\Bbb Z}_2y\}$. Let $p:M\to N$ be the first projection. I know the following.

1. $f$ is not a fibration. But if we also remove $0$ from $N$, then the first projection is a fibration with fiber homeomorphic to ${\Bbb C}$ minus four points.
2. $f_*:\pi_1(M)\to \pi_1(N)$ is a surjection.
3. $\pi_1(M)$ is torsion free. In fact, $M$ is aspherical.

Question: What is ker$f_*$? Is it free? If not, what is its' cohomological dimension?

Comment: Have you looked at https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.06159? Theorem 1.3 seems to apply here.

Comment: Thanks Mark! The paper you referred is under revision. My question is the simplest possible case. So, I am hoping for a direct argument.